# Remix: Global Token Refresh Handling to Prevent Concurrent Calls in Parallel Loaders

Tags: refresh-token, remix, remix.run

Given that Remix runs all loaders in parallel, I'm encountering an issue in my setup where I have an Express backend handling the refresh token actions. Multiple child routes are simultaneously triggering the refresh token middleware, causing a significant overhead. I am looking to implement a mechanism where the token refresh is handled globally and prevents multiple concurrent refresh requests.

Do any of you have experience with or suggestions for efficiently handling token refreshes in Remix, especially in tandem with an Express backend, to prevent multiple child routes from initiating the refresh process at the same time?

Thanks a lot!